# How to force log4cxx to write certain string on top of the log file?

Tags: log4cxx

I want that everytime when log4cxx creates new log file it would write special
string on top (as the first message) of the log file.

How can I force it to do so ?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

You can create your layout from `log4cxx::PatternLayout` and reimplement `appendHeader()`, this function is called from `log4cxx::FileAppender::setFile()` (through `log4cxx::WriterAppender::writeHeader()`)when file created.

Comment: Thank You to inspire me! After implementing that thing I have found the class HTMLLayout in the log4cxx testsuite.